# Do I need to update both Entities in a one-to-many relationship using EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I have two Entities which look like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public decimal AccountBalance { get; set; }

    public virtual Expense Expense { get; set;} 
}

public class Expense
{
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }
    public string ExpenseName { get; set; }
    public decimal ExpenseAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection Accounts { get; }
}
```

If I want to add a new `Expense` to the `DbContext.Expenses` with an `Account` object that is already stored within the `Database`, do I also need to add this new `Expense` to that `Account Entity`?

In my testing there was no way to access the associated `Expenses` from the `Account Model` if I simply create a new `Expense` entity.

Comment: Seems odd. Wouldn't one account have many expenses, rather than one expense being associated with many accounts?

Comment: Yeah, it is odd. Maybe expenses are shared between users/accounts.

Comment: Haha sorry I modified the code for my example to make it more obvious what I meant, it's actually a one-one relationship in my code. But you are right, normally it would be the other way round, Expenses are actually a one-many with budget fields in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

- Add new `Expense` to the expenses collection
- On the already existing `Account` entity set the `Expense` property to be the new entity created.
- Save changes.

Comment: Thank you! I thought as much, just felt it easier to ask than spend a while testing just to be proved wrong at a later date!